# Clean URLS with mod rewrite and URL Encoded characters causes 404?

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, url

I have a web site using `mod_rewrite` to get some clean urls and custom 404 pages. My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?clean_url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What puzzles me is that if the URL contains a `%2F` (url-encoded `/`) the server seems to force a 404. As an example, `http://example.com/category/article` would be a normal article, but then `http://example.com/category%2farticle` gives a server-generated 404 page. (not the custom 404 page)

I wouldn't have expected this... why this is happening? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs `http://example.com/category/article` and `http://example.com/category%2farticle` are not equal.  According to [RFC 2616 §3.2.3](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#sec-3.2.3), reserved characters have special significance (which is, after all, the whole point of URL escaping).  [RFC 2396 §2.2](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#sec-2.2) lists `/` as such a reserved character.  In the context of HTTP URLs, `/` delimits path elements, while `%2f` is a literal slash.

In Apache, [`AllowEncodedSlashes On`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) would prevent the request from being immediately rejected with a 404.